# can not set a count* value into a column?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to save a column count value into another column. my query is

```
(select count(*) from `like_dislike` where `like`='1' and `memeid`=i.id) AS 'like'
```

i want to sum of all like where like=1 and return them as a like value.

Comment: Show your full query where you have define alias as `i` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you want to store the count?

Comment: If you really want anyone to help you please post your complete query which you are trying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try:

```
select count(*) as total_likes from `like_dislike` where `like`='1' and `memeid`=i.id)
```